# what's the difference between (%%)bash and bang(!)

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, shebang

In jupyter notebook, following gcloud commands work with bang(!) but not with %%bash

```
import os

PROJECT = 'mle-1234' 
REGION = 'us-central1' 
BUCKET = 'mle-1234'
```

```
# for bash
os.environ['PROJECT'] = PROJECT
os.environ['BUCKET'] = BUCKET
os.environ['REGION'] = REGION
os.environ['TFVERSION'] = '1.14.0'  # Tensorflow version
```

```
# Set GCP Project and Region
%%bash
gcloud config set project $PROJECT
gcloud config set compute/region $REGION

gcloud config list
```

I get this error message when I execute the last snippet above with %%bash

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-f93912dbcc34>", line 3
    gcloud config set project $[PROJECT]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, project and region values get set with same lines of code but by removing %%bash and prefixing (!) with all gcloud commands.

```
# Set GCP Project and Region
!gcloud config set project $PROJECT
!gcloud config set compute/region $REGION

!gcloud config list
```

Result with using (!)

```
Updated property [core/project].
Updated property [compute/region].

[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-a
[core]
account = my-service-account@mle-1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = mle-1234

What could be the reason for this behavior?
```

Comment: Random guess: `%%bash` requires placement in a magical position on the *first* line, similar to the way a shebang (`#!`) must be on the first line in a script.  What happens if you remove the comment above it and place `%%bash` on the first line?  Any change?

Answer (score 0):

### %%bash

> `%%bash` is considered part of the **[Built-in magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)**. Run cells with bash in a subprocess. This is a shortcut for `%%script bash`. You can combine code from multiple kernels into one notebook. For example:

```
%%HTML
%%python2
%%python3
%%ruby
%%perl
```

implementation:

```
%%bash

factorial()
{
    if [ "$1" -gt "1" ]
    then
        i=`expr $1 - 1`
        j=`factorial $i`
        k=`expr $1 \* $j`
        echo $k
    else
        echo 1
    fi
}

input=5
val=$(factorial $input)
echo "Factorial of $input is : "$val
```

### ! command

> Starting a code cell with a bang character, e.g. !, instructs jupyter to treat the code on that line as an **[OS shell command](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3/jupyter_notebooks_advanced_features.html#Access-to-linux-shell-commands)**

```
!cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION
```

**Output:**

```
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
```

---

> **Answer:** since you are using `gcloud` commands, Jupyter will interpret those as OS shell commands; and therefore, using `!glcoud` will work.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to answer the question at all. Using `%%bash` should (?) cause the subsequent lines to be passed to bash for interpretation, and if that happened, it should have worked... but clearly they are not being passed to bash, because `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is not a bash error.